# Is it possible to have private QR Codes

Tags: qr-code

Is it possible to have some kind of authorization added to the QR code reader process. I don't want a QR code to be read by all scanners. For example
User 1: Gets a QR code by Logging into a website
User 2: Logs in into a native mobile application and scans the QR code generated by User 1

Since User 2 is authorized, the reader should retrieve information from a Database.

If not an authenticated user, the QR code should throw an error stating "Not Authorized"

Comment: How did User 2 see/gets the QR code which was intended for User 1?

Answer (score 1):

A QR code just contains a URl. When User 2 opens the website, they should have to log in. That will tell you if they are authorised.

(OK, a QR code can contain any data - but in most cases, it is a web address.)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a QR code with an encrypted token. Your app can read the code and send an API request to the server with that QR string for verification. The server will decrypt the string, cross-check the token with the user and give you a response after verification.

This URL will be a secured one, not a public URL. That way you won't have to let everyone know what URL you are hitting. Also, this way you can implement your preferred encryption algorithm with your preferred salt.